# Работа с Riak CS через S3 API из Python

Tags: python, amazon-s3

Требуется из приложения Python 3 получать файлы из buckets сервера Riak. Поверх Riak стоит Riak CS с его S3 API. Получить файл через утилиту s3cmd можно так:

```
./s3cmd get s3://bucket_1/21c1422d-bdb7-4b7b-85a9-e4be3df9619b test.out
```

Требуется делать то же самое, но из своего кода.
Так не работает:

```
from riak import RiakClient

client = RiakClient(protocol='http', host='ip_address',http_port=8098)
bucket = client.bucket('bucket_1')

result = bucket.get('21c1422d-bdb7-4b7b-85a9-e4be3df9619b')

with open('test.out', 'rb') as f:
    print(result.data, end='', file=f)
```

Потому что подключение идет не к Riak CS, а к Riak, как я понял. Так тоже не работает:

```
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection

conn = S3Connection(
                    aws_access_key_id='key_id',
                    aws_secret_access_key='secret_key',
                    host='ip_address'
                   )
conn.lookup('bucket_1')
```

Больше я не нашел библиотек S3, где можно было бы настроить подключение к ***своему*** серверу Riak CS с хранилищем S3, а не к AWS.
Буду признателен любой помощи или совету.

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста, что сообщает boto при поптыке коннекта? Boto2 или Boto3? Вы используете https? Если нет, то используйте is_secure=False при подключении.

Comment: @ivan_susanin, если я пытаюсь выполнить `myBucket = conn.get_bucket('monitoring')` то получаю длинный стектрейс, который заканчивается сообщениями об ошибке в модуле socket.py: `gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known` Так что, видимо, вы указали правильное направление. В первую очередь не удается подключиться к серверу.
Я использую, по видимому, boto2. Т.к. в boto3 я не смог найти, как вообще настраивать хост при подключении. is_secure пробовал в обоих вариантах. При `conn.lookup('monitoring')`, я получаю None, как будто бакет не существует.

Comment: Подозреваю, что вместо ip в host надо передавать какой-то объект?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того, что бы подключиться к s3-совместимому хранилищу можно использовать подобный пример:

```
import boto
import boto.s3.connection

access_key = 'access_key'
secret_key = 'secret_key'

conn = boto.connect_s3(
    aws_access_key_id = access_key,
    aws_secret_access_key = secret_key,
    host = 'you_host',
    port = 80, # int
    is_secure = False,
    calling_format = boto.s3.connection.OrdinaryCallingFormat(),
)
```

Обратите внимание, что AWS S3 хранилища используют другой (не OrdinaryCallingFormat) *calling_format* по-умолчанию, В тоже время, s3-campatability хранилища, такие как Ceph, Scality, Minio и др. используют старый формат *calling_format* - *OrdinaryCallingFormat*. Так же boto считает, что порт 80 является дефолтным для http подключения, но можно указать свой, передав параметр port.

Возможно понадобиться довавить you_host в hosts клиентской машины, так как s3 иногда довольно капризен к этому вопросу.

Если всё же есть проблемы и вы не уверены, что s3 endpoint функционирует как нужно. Пробуем

```
curl http(s)://you_host
```

В ответ мы должны увидеть, что-то вроде следующего xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
    <Message>Access Denied.</Message>
    <Key></Key>
    <BucketName></BucketName>
    <Resource>/</Resource>
    <RequestId>3L137</RequestId>
    <HostId>3L137</HostId>
</Error>
```

Это скажет нам о том, что с s3 всё впорядке и нужно искать верную комбинацию пораметров подключения.

Comment: Это помогло, спасибо! Проверил с помощью curl - сервис отвечает, настроил как указанно, и получил `S3ResponseError: 403 Forbidden` Но это уже большой прогресс, до этого я даже не мог понять на правильном ли я пути)